# PreferenceFragmentCompat & Toolbar problem

Tags: android

i'm working with a PreferenceFragmentCompat in my app and i found trouble to show Toolbar in that Fragment. I'm noob at programming in Android so...

this is the definition of mi preferenceFragmentCompat.

```
public class MiCuentaFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

EditTextPreference usuario;
EditTextPreference clave;

@Override
public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle bundle, String s) {
    //addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference_layout);
    setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference_layout, s);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}
```

and this is de definition of his XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<Preference/>
<EditTextPreference
    android:key="opcion_nombreUsuario"
    android:summary="El nombre con el que te identificas dentro de la aplicacion"
    android:title="@string/nombre_usuario_opcion" />

<EditTextPreference
    android:key="opcion_claveUsuario"
    android:summary="Clave que te permite iniciar sesion en la aplicacion"
    android:title="@string/clave_opcion" />

<SwitchPreference
    android:key="opcion_envioNotificacion"
    android:summary="Recibe notificaciones de la aplicacion, noticias e informacion
                            relevante en tu cuenta de correo"
    android:title="@string/notificaciones_opcion"
    android:checked="true"/>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Also I have a NavigationView and a DrawerLayout defined in the ActivityMain with a FrameLayout that is responsible for loading the different fragments.

I made a updateView method that is declared as an interface on the fragments and defined in ActivityMain that is responsible for updating the toolbar depending on the string that is passed as subtitle, but in the case of the PreferenceFragment I do not have a declared toolbar to find it with findviewbyid.

this is mi MainActivity layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/heather_menu_lateral"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_lateral" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and this is my MainActivity.java

```
public void updateToolbar   (String subtitle)   {
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("Parking Control");
    toolbar.setSubtitle(subtitle);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toogle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar,
            R.string.abrir_menu, R.string.cerrar_menu);
    toogle.syncState();
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
    int id = menuItem.getItemId();
    Fragment fragment = null;
    if (id == R.id.Parqueos) {
        //Llama y muestra el fragmento dinamico en el contenedor los registros
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container_main, new ParkeosFragment())
                .commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.MiCuenta) {
        //Llamas al Fragmento de la clase de SettingsPreference
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container_main, new MiCuentaFragment())
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

![1]: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ank6eQEPx3wLhapJODkeaHWigJK1DQ
![2]: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ank6eQEPx3wLhapKvxJ2H72YGOOAjA

Comment: Add your ActivityMain activity and layout code.

Comment: sorry, I'm new on the site and I didn't publish the complete code because the post tutorial told me that I had too much code xD

Comment: Your main activity layout doesn't have a Toolbar? Are you trying to add it dynamically?

Comment: exactly, the method defined as updateToolbar is declared in the fragment as an interface and defined in the MainActivity to update the visibility of the Toolbar of each fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your layout seems to be missing the `Toolbar`, try the following,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:openDrawer="start">

    <!-- This LinearLayout represents the contents of the screen  -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <!-- The main content view where fragments are loaded -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/heather_menu_lateral"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_lateral" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Now, rather than provide a `Toolbar` in each `Fragment`, you can programmatically hide/remove the `Toolbar`in fragments that you don't need it.

Comment: Cool, mark the answer as correct if it answered the question. Cheers.